# Python not finding libraries in sys.path unless stated in bash PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

This Python script shows that its path contains `/home/web/public_html/module/disc/static/python/lib/python2.4/site-packages`:

```
$ python serverTest.py 
This is my sys.path:
['/home/web/public_html/module/disc/static/python/lib/python2.4/site-packages', 
 '/home/web/public_html/module/disc/static/python',
 '/usr/lib64/python24.zip',     
 '/usr/lib64/python2.4',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk', 
 '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages', 
 '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/Numeric',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serverTest.py", line 27, in ?
    import simplejson as json
ImportError: No module named simplejson

$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/web/public_html/module/disc/static/python/lib/python2.4/site-packages

$ python serverTest.py 
Hello, world!
```

It can be seen that although the directory is in `sys.path` the script cannot find `simplejson` which is installed there. However, when I add the same path to `PYTHONPATH` in Bash, then `simplejson` is found. How can I fix it so that `simplejson` is available without setting the Bash variable?

**EDIT:**

```
>>> sys.path
['/home/webtov/public_html/module/discoapi/static/python',
'',
'/home/webtov/public_html/module/discoapi/static/python/lib/python2.4/site-packages', 
'/home/webtov/local/',
'/home/webtov/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/',
'/usr/lib64/python24.zip',
'/usr/lib64/python2.4/',
'/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload']

>>> json.__path__
['/home/webtov/public_html/module/discoapi/static/python/lib/python2.4/site-packages', 
'/home/webtov/public_html/module/discoapi/static/python',
'',
'/home/webtov/public_html/module/discoapi/static/python/lib/python2.4/site-packages',  
'/home/webtov/local/',
'/home/webtov/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/',
'/usr/lib64/python24.zip',
'/usr/lib64/python2.4/',
'/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload']
```

Comment: Not an answer, but why on Earth are you putting libraries in your public_html directory?

Comment: `.pth`-files are probably not processed in the first example if you are adding the path manually. `python -S serverTest.py` should fail in the second example if this is the case. What is `sys.path`, `json.__path__` in the second example?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. This is a plugin for phpFox which needs to run on webhosts that do not have `json` or `simplejson` installed (such as Arvixe). The libraries are provided as part of the plugin for these hosts. Ugly, I know, but the users of these plugins are not expected to have the technical ability to deal with the libraries not being installed.

Comment: Thanks, J.F.Sebastian, I added the info to the question.